# Geometry - Prove that these 3 points don't lie on the same line

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Rectangular coordinate system in the plane
The Points are given - $A(5,0) B(1,3) C(-2,0)$. Prove that these $3$ points don't lie on the same line and find the surface of the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Once this is your first time posting here, it is a pattern to show your own effort and tell us where you got stuck in order to get a better help.

Comment: Hint: if the three points $(x_i,y_i)$ did lie on the same line, they would all satisfy an equation $y = kx + m$, where $k$ and $m$ are two constants.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks the OP's own effort and looks like seeking help for homework problems.

Comment: @Arnaldo well I don't really know how to start

Comment: What line do $A$ and $C$ obviously determine? Is $B$ on it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it isn't said

Comment: Can you draw a picture showing these three points and the triangle they make?

Comment: @EthanBolker just attack them to each other

Comment: No, peter, it isn't said – but *you* can figure it out! Can't you see what line $A$ and $C$ determine? What do you know about lines and coordinate systems and equations and such?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "Carcass"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson i mean't rectangular

Comment: can i get some formula or something?

Comment: Do you know anything at all about lines in a rectangular coordinate system, peter? m.se is not meant to make up for weeks of missed classes. Surely you have some study materials to get you up to speed. Or some teacher you can go to see to explain your predicament?

Comment: May you, by any chance, have been taught about vectors in a recent past ? If yes, do you know what are 'colinear' vectors ?

Comment: It's rude to vandalize your posts, please don't do that instead you should try improving the question so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, you asked for a formula. This is a **bad idea**. The purpose of mathematics is to *understand*, not to plug numbers into formulas, and we are not computers.

So let me give some steps you can take to solve the problem.

1. Draw a pictures! Take some graph paper, or make a grid on some ordinary paper. Find the points $(5,0)$, $(1,3)$, and $(-2, 0)$. Color them in. Do they appear to lie on a straight line?
2. Do they look like they form a triangle? What do you know about triangles and their areas? Do you know the formula for area of a triangle - do you understand why it is true?
3. What would the area of their triangle be if they all were on a straight line? Perhaps finding their area can help you solve your first problem as well!

Comment: ok so obviously they are not on the same line... but still I need to prove it using mathematic rules like matrixes, collenear stuff... not by the picture

Comment: @peter Exactly! The picture gives insight, the mathematics exist to codify that insight. What do you know about the area of a triangle where all three points are not on the same line? What's the relationship between that and matrices/vectors?

Comment: that's the things i'm struggling with

Comment: @peter Yep :) The struggle is important. You're using vectors and determinants, right? Look up "cross product." Or directly compute the area of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually solve problems like this by "getting a formula",  you solve them by *thinking*.

Draw a picture of the coordinate plane, put a dot at each of the three points. See whether they are on a line.

Then you should be able to say in just a few words why $B$ is not on the line containing $A$ and $C$.

Finally, you can use a formula to find the area of the triangle.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for the triangle (0,0)(a,b)(c,d)
Area=1/2 [ ad-bc]

Change your coordinates 
(5,0)----->(0,0)
(-2,0)--->(-7,0)
(1,3)----->(-4,3)
Area=1/2 [ -21+0]=21/2 answer